# Can we generate a sub-sigma-algebra using a sub-pi-system?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and let $P$ be a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) generating $\Sigma$.

Take now a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'\subseteq \Sigma$. Let $P'=P\cap\Sigma'$. Note that $P'$ is again a $\pi$-system, which by construction is contained in $\Sigma'$, and so it generates a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma'$.

Can we say that $P'$ generates the whole of $\Sigma'$? (If not, are there extra requirements?)

I'm trying to use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, but I get stuck - I'm feeling that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Take $P$ to be the set of Intervalls $(a,\infty)$ and let $\Sigma'$ be the sigma algebra of **symmetric** (around the origin) Borel sets.